# turn off hibernate automatic entity discovery in persistance.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to turn off hibernate automatic entity discovery as I get an error about duplicat entity with same name!
how can i do it in `persistance.xml`?

Thanks.

Comment: just add `<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />` to the `<properties>` tag of `persistence`

Comment: are you sure it should be class?? i still get the same error

Comment: you use hibernate with annotations or XML?

Comment: try this also `value="class, hbm"`

Comment: @FarhangAmary'Ferhęg' i use hibernate with annotations

Comment: I was in hurry when reading your question, I thought you have problem with turning it on, sorry. but it's better to show us the necessary content of persistence.xml file

Comment: remove the content of value I mean try this `value=""` if you want to turn it off, and give a feedback plz

Comment: you mean "exclude-unlisted-classes"

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="" />
    </properties>
```

thanks to FarhangAmary'Ferhęg comment

Answer (score 0):

According to [JPA specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a12305) and [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_metadata_scanning_options), to disable entity auto-discovery **exclude-unlisted-classes** element must be set to **true**.

```
<persistence-unit name="my_pu_name" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>my.entity.Foo</class>
    <class>my.entity.Bar</class>
    <class>my.entity.Baz</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="some.property" value="some_value" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```